# onClickListener() is not working properly for textview

Tags: java, android, android-intent, textview, onclicklistener

For a better UI, I thought of using TextView in place of Button. When a TextView is clicked, the next page of the application should appear, in my case, it is the signup page(I want to go from login to signup page). I have defined setOnClickListener() in the Java file and then use the intent to go to another activity by clicking on that textView but, I don't know why when I click on the textView(Signup here) instead of taking me to the signup page, it goes to home page.

[Here are the names of the file I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILPLO.png)
*** Here is my XML file for login

---

[Here is the image of the page I am creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bahhE.png)

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnlg"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_btn"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:shadowRadius="@integer/material_motion_duration_short_1"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck,TextContrastCheck,TextContrastCheck" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/noAccount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/don_t_have_an_account"
            android:textColor="#606060"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SignUpLn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_here"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TextContrastCheck" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/or"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#606060"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_btn_G"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_btn"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageG"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/glogo"
            tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck,ImageContrastCheck"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageG"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_in_with_the_google"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_btn_A"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_btn"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/apple_image"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/applelogo"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/apple_image"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_in_with_the_apple"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TextContrastCheck" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fb_image_btn"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_btn"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fcimage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook2"
            tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck,ImageContrastCheck"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fcimage"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_in_with_the_facebook"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TextContrastCheck" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**here is the java file for login
**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
    SignUpLn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SignUpLn);
    SignUpLn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent SignUpLn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),signUp.class);
            startActivity(SignUpLn);
        }
    });
    btnlg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlg);
    btnlg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(login);
        }
    });
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnRPZ.png)

Comment: Could you show signUp and HomeScreen file.